# Graphic of the probability distribution function : How does it works?

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

Here is the graphic of the probability distribution function for a random variable $X$.[image]

How can I find the distribution of $Y=-X$?

By definition the  distribution function for a random variable is $F_X(x)=P(X\le x)$ and the distribution is given by $\sum_{x\in X(\Omega)}P(X=x)$. Here $X(\Omega)=\Bbb{R}$ so that $Y(\Omega)=\Bbb{R}$, right? I have to find $\sum_{x\in \Bbb{R}} P(Y=x)=\sum_{x\in \Bbb{R}} P(X=-x)$, right?

And we have $P(X< -1)=0, \quad P(X\ge 1)=1$. How can I continue? (If what I was doing is correct)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable $X$ is neither discrete nor continuous.
Since it's not discrete, you can't just use $\sum$ notation to compute
$F_X(x)$ at every point,
and since it's not continuous you can't just integrate a pdf to get $F_X$.
But since you have already been given $F_X$, you don't need to be concerned about
how you could or could not obtain it.

The distribution of $Y$ is $F_Y(x) = P(Y \leq x) = P(-X \leq x).$
You know $P(X \leq x)$ for every $x$;
can you figure out what $P(-X \leq x)$ is for every $x$ from that information?

**Reminder:** *Don't overthink the problem.*
The graph has all the information you need to know about $F_X$;
you're just being asked to sketch a related graph.
You *do* need to be careful not to sketch the value of $P(-X < x)$ 
instead of  $P(-X \leq x)$ (there is a difference between these, since the
distribution is not continuous), but you don't need to be able to
compute any of these probabilities using integration, sums, or
very much of anything except the graph itself.

Comment: Good point! I just cannot figure out $P(X\le x)$ for $-1<x<1$?

Comment: If the graph is as it appears, $F_X(x)=P(X\leq x)$ is linear between the values $F_X(-1^+)=\frac13$ and $F_X(1^-)=\frac23.$ The function $F_X(x) = \frac12 + \frac16 x$ for $-1<x<1$ looks like what you want.

Comment: This was I had but I was not sure, nevertheless to compute the expected value I need integration right? Thanks. (+1 and accept soon).

Comment: Did you need to find an expected value? It wasn't mentioned in the problem. If you need that, you may want to express $X$ as a composite of two variables: with $\frac23$ probability it's equally likely to be $-1$ or $1$, and with $\frac13$ probability it's uniformly distributed over the interval $(-1,1).$ The expected value should be fairly obvious by symmetry.

Answer (score 1):

The distribution $P_X$ of $X$ has a part with a density (with respect to the Lebesgue measure) and a part made of Dirac measures. Using rigorous notations, one can write $$P_X(\mathrm dx)=\frac13\delta_{-1}(\mathrm dx)+\frac13\delta_{1}(\mathrm dx)+\frac16\mathbf 1_{[-1,1]}(x)\mathrm dx,$$ but notations are not so important here. What might be more important is to realize that $P_X$ puts mass $\frac13$ on $1$, puts mass $\frac13$ on $-1$, and has a part uniform on $[-1,1]$ with total mass $\frac13$. In particular, $P_X$ is symmetric hence $Y=-X$ has the same distribution $P_Y=P_X$.

Finally, note that distributions are mostly useful to compute expectations and here, for every measurable function $u$ (either nonnegative, or such that $u$ is integrable on $[-1,1]$ for the Lebesgue measure), one has $$E(u(X))=\frac13u(-1)+\frac13u(1)+\frac16\int_{-1}^1u(x)\mathrm dx,$$ and from this formula, it should be apparent that $E(u(X))=E(u(-X))=E(u(Y))$ for every $u$, that is, once again, that $Y$ has the same distribution as $X$.

Comment: I accepted David K's answer too quickly I imagine.. Thanks for this answer, very clear.

Answer (score 0):

The last line is correct. You have to consider, that you have a mixed random variable. It is  a continuous and discrete variable.

First you should write down the pdf of X.

$f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{3}, \text{if} \ x=-1 \\ \frac{1}{6} ,\text{if} -1<x<1  \\ \frac{1}{3}, \text{if} \ x=1 \\ 0, \text{else}  \end{cases}$

Now you can solve the equations for every part of x.

First interval: $x=-1 \Rightarrow -x=1$ Thus $f(y)=\frac{1}{3}, \text{if} \ y=1$

Second interval:  $-1<x<1 \Rightarrow -1<x \vee x<1 \Rightarrow -x<1 \vee -1<-x \Rightarrow f(y)=\frac{1}{6}, \text{if}-1 <y<1$

You go on like this.

Comment: For $x=1$ it's $1$ no? I don't understand how can you compute for $-1<x<1$? For the rest I understand how does it works. To compute the expected value, I have to compute the area between $-1<x<1$? (and sure +1)

Comment: $X$ does not have a pdf, at least not in the usual sense. Note that for $f(x)$ as written above, $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) dx = \frac13,$ so $f(x)$ is not a pdf.

Comment: @DavidK Why? It's only for a density function that the integral is $1$ no?

Comment: @Gato I wrote down the probability function, not the cummulative probability funtion. You see, that $F(x=1^-)=\int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{6} \ dx=1/3$ and $F(x=1)=1$. Thus $f(x=1)=F(x=1)-F(x=1^-)=2/3$. To compute the expected value, between $-1 \leq x \leq 1$, you calculate $E(x)=-1\cdot \frac{1}{3}+\int_{-1}^1 x\cdot \frac{1}{6}+1 \cdot \frac{1}{3}$

Comment: pdf = "probability density function" the way I learned it. But if you're a little more careful how you write it, you can make a useful statement with the three cases for $f(x)$ given in this answer.

Comment: @calculus I think you meant to make $F_X(x=1^-)=\frac23.$ Otherwise you wouldn't get $\frac13$ when you subtract $F_X(x=1^-)$ from $F_X(x=1)=1$.

Comment: @Gato Ihad a typo. I wrote down the probability function, not the cummulative probability funtion. You see, that $F(x=1^-)=\frac{1}{3}+\int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{6} \ dx=2/3$ and $F(x=1)=1$. Thus $f(x=1)=F(x=1)-F(x=1^-)=1/3$. To compute the expected value, between $-1 \leq x \leq 1$, you calculate $E(x)=-1\cdot \frac{1}{3}+\int_{-1}^1 x\cdot \frac{1}{6} \ dx+1 \cdot \frac{1}{3}$

Comment: @DavidK Yes, I forgot $f(x=-1)=1/3$. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: I still think this is much more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: There are some problems with the formulation of your answer, for example the identity $f(-1)=\frac13$ is wrong if $f$ is the PDF. Actually the random variable $X$ has no PDF, more precisely the distribution of $X$ is not entirely described by a PDF.

Comment: @Did I didn´t have a better expression. I you have one, you are welcome. Maybe we can call it a probability function of a mixed random variable. But I think, that the name of the function is not the most important issue of this exercise.

Comment: @calculus Yes this is important because there is a standard terminology in this domain, established for many years, and failing to adopt it is misleading. Here the distribution of $X$ has **no** PDF but it may be described by its CDF (or, and this might be preferable, one can explain that a part of the distribution of $X$ has a PDF and another part is made of two Dirac measures).

Comment: @Did I am a bit lost with english notation. I have to learn them.

Comment: @Gato Sorry but I fail to understand your comment.

Comment: @Did I am not an english native: the probabilistic vocabulary is not the same (apparently). (yeah 'notation' was not the expected word).